# Reverse animations aren't working properly with javascript and keyframes

Tags: javascript, css, animation, sass

I'm trying to animate the navigation overlay to come in from the right (which is working perfectly!), but it's not working when I try to reverse the process. I'm wondering why. Please review the code below and see if you can help me.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="nav-element">
    <h1>header</h1>
    <figure class="nav-img">
        <img src="images/svg/menu.svg" alt="Hamburger Menu" id="nav-open">
    </figure>
</nav>

<section id="overlay" class="overlay">
    <header>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <figure class="nav-img">
            <img src="images/svg/menu-close.svg" alt="Close Menu" id="nav-close">
        </figure>
    </header>

    <ul>
        <li class="nav-button"><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        <li class="nav-button"><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
        <li class="nav-button"><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
        <li class="nav-button"><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

**SCSS**

```
.show-menu {
    display: block;
    animation: slide-menu 0.5s ease-in forwards;

    header {
        animation: show-x 1s 0.5s forwards;
    }

    li:nth-of-type(1) {
        animation: item-1 0.5s 0.5s linear forwards;
    }

    li:nth-of-type(2) {
        animation: item-1 0.5s 0.7s linear forwards;
    }

    li:nth-of-type(3) {
        animation: item-1 0.5s 0.9s linear forwards;
    }

    li:nth-of-type(4) {
        animation: item-1 0.5s 1.1s linear forwards;
    }
}

.hide-menu {
    display: block;
    animation: slide-menu 0.5s 1.1s ease-in forwards;

    header {
        animation: hide-x 1s 0.5s forwards;
    }

    li:nth-of-type(1) {
        animation: item-hide 0.5s linear forwards;
    }

    li:nth-of-type(2) {
        animation: item-hide 0.5s 0.9s linear forwards;
    }

    li:nth-of-type(3) {
        animation: item-hide 0.5s 0.7s linear forwards;
    }

    li:nth-of-type(4) {
        animation: item-hide 0.5s 0.5s linear forwards;
    }
}

@keyframes slide-menu {
    from {
        transform: scaleX(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }
}

@keyframes show-x {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes item-1 {
    from {
        transform: translateX(10%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes hide-menu {
    from {
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }
    to {
        transform: scaleX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes hide-x {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes item-hide {
    from {
        transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(10%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

document.getElementById('nav-open').addEventListener('click', function() {
    overlay.classList.add('show-menu');
})

document.getElementById('nav-close').addEventListener('click', function() {
    overlay.classList.add('hide-menu');
    overlay.classList.remove('show-menu');
})
```

Can anyone help me why the animation isn't "reversed" and the menu closes the same way it opens? 
So first the items move on the X-axis and disappear, then the header content fades, and lastly the overlay moves from the X-axis and disappears.

Comment: I tried your animation with the code you added, but also the entry animation is really strange. Could you please explain us more clearly (or maybe that's just my problem of understanding, sorry) what animation you would like to do? Both the entry and exit one. Also, should the exit animation only start when you click on "close menu"? 
If you click on "Hamburger menu" again when the entry animation ends, nothing has to happen? By default, is it correct that `#overlay` is visible? Thank you.

Comment: Please see this gif: https://gyazo.com/be355573416342f16250b4b5c4c3a762
All I want is when I close the menu that the animation is reversed and it closes with the same animation, first fading and moving the button items and then closing the menu sliding out to the left

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS for the .hide-menu, Adding the `reverse` property will reverse the animation when clicking the hide button:

```
.hide-menu {
   display: block;
   animation: slide-menu 0.5s 1.1s ease-in reverse;

   header {
       animation: hide-x 1s 0.5s reverse;
   }

   li:nth-of-type(1) {
       animation: item-hide 0.5s linear reverse;
   }

   li:nth-of-type(2) {
       animation: item-hide 0.5s 0.9s linear reverse;
   }

   li:nth-of-type(3) {
       animation: item-hide 0.5s 0.7s linear reverse;
   }

   li:nth-of-type(4) {
       animation: item-hide 0.5s 0.5s linear reverse;
   }
```

}

Heres a [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/r8xtwkpd/1/)

Comment: It's still just disappearing and not applying the animations

Comment: Did you take a look at the JSFiddle? If that is not the behaviour you are wanting to achieve then you may have to provide a little more information on what you are aiming for

Comment: It's not working on the JSFiddle either when you close the menu